CocoaPods Installation Fails with Firebase in Flutter on macOS (pod install issue)
Issue:
I'm having trouble installing CocoaPods for Firebase in my Flutter project on macOS.
When I run pod install, I get this error:
rovshenhojayev@Rovshens-MacBook-Air ios % pod install
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/bin/pod install

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

   CocoaPods : 1.15.2
        Ruby : ruby 3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) [arm64-darwin23]
    RubyGems : 3.3.3
        Host : macOS 15.0.1 (24A348)
       Xcode : 16.0 (16A242d)
         Git : git version 2.39.5 (Apple Git-154)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/


### Plugins


cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0

### Podfile

ruby
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end


### Error

JSON::ParserError - Failed to parse JSON at file: '/Users/rovshenhojayev/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.67.0/gRPC-C++.podspec.json'.

unexpected token at '"src/core/lib/'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:66:in `rescue in from_json'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:61:in `from_json'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:759:in `from_string'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:733:in `from_file'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:188:in `specification'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:58:in `block in specification_name'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `each'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `specification_name'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:216:in `search'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `block in search'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `select'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `search'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in `create_set_from_sources'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in `find_cached_set'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in `specifications_for_dependency'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by!'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59:in `sort_dependencies'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in `push_state_for_requirements'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:744:in `require_nested_dependencies_for'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:727:in `activate_new_spec'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1082:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=Failed+to+parse+JSON+at+file%3A+%27%2FUsers%2Frovshenhojayev%2F.cocoapods%2Frepos%2Ftrunk%2FSpecs%2Fc%2F8%2F7%2FgRPC-C%2B%2B%2F1.67.0%2FgRPC-C%2B%2B.podspec.json%27.%0A%0Aunexpected+token+at+%27%22src%2Fcore%2Flib%2F%27&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new

Environment:
macOS: Version 15.0.1
Flutter: 3.24.3
Xcode: 16.0
CocoaPods: 1.15.2
Tried:
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod repo update + pod install
Still facing the same issue. Any suggestions?

Try removing the lock file and running pod install again.

Which one pubspec.lock or Podfile.lock

Remove Podfile.lock

Try downgrade your packages to this:
  firebase_auth: ^4.20.0 # [https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth]
  firebase_core: ^2.32.0 # [https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core]

don’t worry about that, hire a camp for today.
I suffered for a couple of hours and then still came up against this:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/13650
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/13761
So, then the standard procedure:

flutter clean
delete Podfile.lock

and in terminal:

cd ios
pod install --repo-update
flutter pub get


Just tried but it says need to update.
Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
pod repo update
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 16.
